# Fail to deploy when have a getter for the specific field

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate entity class with discriminator column "colA". However, when I try to map it to a normal field in the entity class also with a getter method, it will fail the deployment. Below is the entity file

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tableOne")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="colA", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=16)
public class TableOneEntity {

     @Column(name="colA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
     private String colA;
     public String getColA() {
          return colA;
     }
     ...
}
```

Please note that the deployment will work if I add @Transient on the getter method. However, that's not an option to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to add the stacktrace

Comment: also, if you add a setter.. is the error still there?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski, yes. Adding a setter won't fix the issue as long as the getter is there.

Comment: We did something similar and I'm not sure if this makes a difference (we'd need to see the stacktrace to known what Hibernate complains about) but our `@Column` also contains `nullable = false` and your entity has an additional annotation `@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)`.

Comment: @Thomas, when you say @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true), you mean you guys have it not mine. Right?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski, where should I add stacktrace? in the getter?

Comment: Yes, remove the "y" from that "your" (it's meant to be "our") - my bad :)

Comment: @Zhazi the deployment fails... with an error. Post the complete and exact error stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. I got the answer. Just move

```
@Column(name="colA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

on top of the getter instead of the field. Still don't know why. Thanks for everyone replied.